# AngularJS Custom form validator for custom directive form controls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on an app with custom form controls which need to be validated before clicking a Next button. For standard HTML form controls, angular's built-in validation is quite nice, allowing me to bind my Next button with a `ng-disabled` on the `form.$valid` value. However, I am having trouble getting custom validation working in a rather difficult control. Here is my situation:

- I have a custom directive for my form control (a component called `mySlider`)
- `mySlider` wraps a 3rd-party component [angular-slider](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider) -- yes, I know it's deprecated
- **We want to validate that the user has clicked the slider. The Next button should not be enabled if the user has not clicked the slider control.**
- I tried to create this custom validation by adding a `has-changed` attribute to the 3rd party directive element, and updating it on-click, however it does not seem to be working as expected.
- I tried to examine how the [built-in validations work](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/angular.js) (ex: try searching for `var requiredDirective`), as well as reading the [Angular Forms Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-) but it's still a little unclear
- We have a requirement to not use jQuery, jQuery UI/Mobile etc, however it must also work for mobile touch events

[See my Plunk and help](http://plnkr.co/edit/UVUpiUaJHVYt4Wc23c4U?p=preview) 
 - please fork if you're going to edit. The custom validator and custom Slider directive is in `script.js` while the 3rd-party directive is in `angular-slider.js`.

Comment: I'll have something for you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the $setValidity function on your form model to toggle the validity state of the slider.  This will give you the flexibility you desire to make complicated form rules which each component being different.

Here is working code to solve your problem.  I converted your ng-change to an ng-click that compared begin and after values [Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0bkWeb?p=preview)

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // Slider init
    scope.max = 100;
    scope.min = 0;
    scope.initial = 50;
    scope.sliderValue = scope.initial;
    //Set validity to false by default
    scope.myForm.mySliderControl.$setValidity('hasChanged',false); 

    // ng-change is not coded with this example, converted to ng-click
    scope.change = function(){
      if(scope.initial != scope.sliderValue){
          console.log("I have changed!");
          scope.myForm.mySliderControl.$setValidity('hasChanged',true);
      } 
    };
  }
```

On a side note.  Several issues that compounded to cause your problem:

1. `angular-slider` is not coded to enable the ng-change functionality you were attempting to use
2. Your `mySlider` directive should have an isolate scope and pass options via a config object.  Currently, it is on the same scope as the controller which means the directive can't really be reused.
3. Compounding directive here only adds complications

Comment: Thanks for the post--that's helpful. One drawback to this approach, though, is that I couldn't just add `my-slider` to `myOtherForm`. Is there a way to make the reference to `myForm` somehow more generic?

Comment: I think I know what to do... I could pass in the form name to the `mySlider` directive, then dynamically refer to the form with `scope[formName][mySliderName].$setValidity`. Let's see if it works...

Comment: When I make custom directives like the one you are talking about, I typically have an options attribute which is linked a scope object which passes in my configurations settings `<my-slider options="slider1Options"></my-slider>` and $scope.slider1Options.  From there I can set-up two way data binding (pass in scope.myForm.mySliderControl as a property on the object).

Comment: I may be going about this the wrong way, but I'm still unable to dynamically use this technique. [See Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJEHXxRaB4axtGpafvAM?p=preview) I wasn't able to call the `$setValidity` using the bracket approach.

Comment: I got it!!! For whichever reason, passing in the `myForm` object in a different attribute worked. See same plunk as in last comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it!  Much, much better solution than your initial piece of code from a reusable directive standpoint.